# accessoryType in the left side

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

Is there any way to set the `accessoryType` of the cell to be in the left side?
the code i use:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

in this condition the `accessoryType` button is on the right side and i want it in the left side.
I tried also to build a custom cell be in the IB when i chose accessory it put it automatic in the right side also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can set the cell's `imageView.image` [property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW45) to a `UIImage` of your choice.

If you re-use Apple's disclosure button images, you might run into issues getting your app accepted, so you might want to create your own disclosure icons.